# Argument of type '() => () => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

My code is:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector('body').style['background-color'] = 'rgba(173, 232, 244,0.2)';
        window.$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:hide']);

        return async () => {
            window.$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:show']);
            document.querySelector('body').style['background-color'] = '#ffffff';
            if (router.query.id) {
                const resDoc = await firebase.firestore().doc(`documents/${router.query.id}`).get();
                if (resDoc.exists) {
                    await clearDocPrediction(router.query.id);
                }
            }
        };
    }, []);
```

Now the reason I'm returning is because I believe that it performs function cleanup on unload, so I need to keep that. This is some sort of build error that I'm not quite sure how to resolve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An effect callback is supposed to return void, yours returns a _promise_ of void.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Effect's callback function should return `void`, e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => { // callback; it returns void
  console.log("Hi")
}, [])
```

Or

It should return a "**cleanup**" function of type `() => void`, e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hi")
  return () => { // cleanup function of type : () => void
    console.log("Cleanup")
  }
}, [])
```

You are getting the error because the cleanup function in your code is not of type `() => void`, but of type `() => Promise<void>`, e.g.:

> Argument of type '() => () => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'. Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Hi")
  return async () => { // WRONG
    console.log("Cleanup")
  }
}, [])
```

Hence, here is how you can refactor your "cleanup" function to fix it:

```
return () => { // Remove async from here
  const clear = async () => { // Create a new async function: clear
    // write your cleanup code here
  };
  clear() // Call the clear() function
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The `useEffect` callback should have return type void. So you can't return a Promise:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector('body').style['background-color'] = 'rgba(173, 232, 244,0.2)';
        window.$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:hide']);

        window.$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:show']);
        document.querySelector('body').style['background-color'] = '#ffffff';
        if (router.query.id) {
            firebase.firestore()
                .doc(`documents/${router.query.id}`)
                .get()
                .then((resDoc) => {
                    if (resDoc.exists) {
                        clearDocPrediction(router.query.id);
                    }
                });
        }
}, []);
```